# In Python, is it possible to unpack a dict without passing it to a function?

Tags: python, dictionary, unpack

I have a dict

```
dict = {
   'key1': 'value1',
   'key2': 'value2' 
}
```

and would like to unpack it to

```
key1 = 'value1'
key2 = 'value2'
```

I know that if I do

```
def some_func(key1, key2):
    # do stuff with key1 and key2
```

and then call

```
some_func(**dict)
```

then in my function I will have access to those variables.

Is there a way to get these values out without having to call the function with the dict as an argument or requiring:

```
key1 = dict['key1']
key2 = dict['key2']
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You already have a namespace, the dictionary itself.

Comment: The referenced question isn't quite what you want. You can do `globals().update(my_dict)`.

Comment: Also see [_Why you don't want to dynamically create variables_](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).